# Awk - replace coumn 2 in table 1 from coumn 2 in table 2 based on matching data in column 1 (common between tables)

Tags: regex, bash, perl, awk

After my company purchased new servers I'm doing a top-down upgrade of the server room. since all the hardware is changing I'm not able to use bare-metal cloning tool to migrate. Using the `newusers` command from Debian I am able to create in bulk all the users from the old server. For the /etc/shadow file, you can copy the second column from your shadow.sync (from the old server) file into the second column of the associated account in the new system. This will transfer the passwords for your accounts to the new system. However I'm not sure how to do this programmatically using awk (or something else I can integrate into my shell script I already have setup).

shadow.sync contains the following (users & passwords changed for security reasons) This is the file to be copied INTO the current shadow file which looks almost identical except the data in the second column has the INCORECT values.

An in-depth explanation of the fields for the /etc/shadow file can be found [here](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/understanding-etcshadow-file/)

```
user1:$6$HiwQEKYDgT$xYU9F3Wv0jFWHmZxN60nFMkTqWn87RRIOvx7Epp57rOmdHN9plJgjhC.jRVVNc1.HUaqSpX/ZcCEFSn6RmQQA0:17531::0:99999:7:::
user2:$6$oOuwJtrIKk$THLsfDppLI8QVw9xEOAaIoZ90Mcz3xGukVdyWGJJqygsavtXvtJ8X9ECc0CfuGzHp0pHNSAqdZY9TAzF5YKLc.:17531::0:99999:7:::
user3:$6$IEHAyRsokQ$e5K3RicE.PUAej8IxG9GnF/SUl1NQ57pqzUVuAzsP8.89SNhuaKE1W7kG5P4hbzV23Bb2zWHx353t.e9ERSVy.:17531::0:99999:7:::
user4:$6$lFOIUQvxdb$W5ITiH/Y021xw1vo8uw6ZtIOmfKjnNnC/SttQjN85MHtLbFeQ2Th5kfAIijXC81CRG4T0kJQ3rzRNRSyQHjyb1:17531::0:99999:7:::
user5:$6$RZbtYxWiwE$lnP8.tTbs0JbLZg5FsmPR8QvrJARbcRuJi2nYm1okwjfkWPkj212mBPjVF1BTo2hVCxLGSw64Cp6DgXheacSx.:17531::0:99999:7:::
```

Essentially i need to match column 1 (username) between the sync file and the shadow file and copy column 2 from the sync file over-top of the same column on the actual shadow file. Doing this by hand would be terrible as I have 90 servers that I'm migrating with over 900 users total.

Random shadow.sync file for demonstration was generated using:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import random, string, crypt, datetime

userList = ['user1','user2','user3','user4','user5']
dateNow = (datetime.datetime.utcnow() - datetime.datetime(1970,1,1)).days

for user in userList:
        randomsalt = ''.join(random.sample(string.ascii_letters,10))
        randompass = ''.join(random.sample(string.ascii_letters,10))
        print("%s:%s:%s::0:99999:7:::" % (user, crypt.crypt(randompass, "$6$"+randomsalt), dateNow))
```

Please note this python script was ONLY for demonstration and not for actual production data. As users are added to the server the /etc/shadow file is generated with the password presented on the command line. The Original data (from shadow.sync) needs to be "Merged" with the data in /etc/shadow after the `newusers` command is run (which essentially sets every password to the letter x)

Comment: Post the desired output and some code you've tried (show some effort!).

Comment: @PesaThe although i would have preferred an AWK or even perl script as they are much faster at processing data in bulk i fixed it, thanks for the help.

Answer (score -1):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
with open('/etc/shadow','rb') as file:
  for line in file:
    TargetLine = line.rstrip().split(":")
    with open('shadow.sync','rb') as shadow:
      for row in shadow:
        SyncLine = row.rstrip().split(":")
        if TargetLine[0] == SyncLine[0]:
          TargetLine[1] = SyncLine[1]
          break
    print "NEW MODIFIED LINE: %s" % ":".join(TargetLine)
```

This will open the /etc/shadow file and loop through the lines. For each line on the `/etc/shadow` file we loop through the `shadow.sync` file once a match for the usernames `TargetLine[0] == SyncLine[0]` the password field is modified and the loop is broken.
If a match is NOT found (username in /etc/shadow but NOT in the shadow.sync file) the `if` block on the inner loop falls through and the line is left untouched the results are handled on the final `print` statement. As this answers the question I will leave the data output and file manipulation up to  the user.

Answer (score -1):

```
use Data::Dumper;

# we only need to process the sync file once -
# and store what we find in a hash (dictionary)

open $fh1, '<', 'shadow.sync.txt';

while (<$fh1>)
{
    m/^([^:]+):(.*)$/;

    $hash->{$1} = $2;
}

close $fh1;

# this shows us what we found & stored

print Dumper $hash;

# now we'll process the shadow file which needs updating -
# here we output a side-by-side comarison of what the passwords
# currently are & what they will be updated to (from the hash)

open $fh2, '<', 'shadow.txt';
open $fh3, '>', 'shadow.UPDATED.txt';

while (<$fh2>)
{
    m/^([^:]+):(.*)$/;

    printf ( "%s => %s\n",   $1, $2 );
    printf ( "%s => %s\n\n", $1, $hash->{$1} );

    printf $fh3 ( "%s:%s\n", $1, $hash->{$1} );
}

close $fh3;
close $fh2;
```

Sample output:

```
$VAR1 = {
      'user5' => '$6$RZbtYxWiwE$lnP8w64Cp6DgXheacSx.:17531::0:99999:7:::',
      'user1' => '$6$HiwVVNc1.HUaqSpX/ZcCEFSn6RmQQA0:17531::0:99999:7:::',
      'user4' => '$6$lFOIUQv1CRG4T0kJQ3rzRNRSyQHjyb1:17531::0:99999:7:::',
      'user3' => '$6$P8.89SNhu23Bb2zWHx353t.e9ERSVy.:17531::0:99999:7:::',
      'user2' => '$6$Cc0CfuGzHp0pHNSAqdZY9TAzF5YKLc.:17531::0:99999:7:::'
    };

user1 => $6$RANDOM1RANDOM1RANDOM1RANDOM1:17531::0:99999:7:::
user1 => $6$HiwVVNc1.HUaqSpX/ZcCEFSn6RmQQA0:17531::0:99999:7:::

user2 => $6$RANDOM2RANDOM2RANDOM2RANDOM2:17531::0:99999:7:::
user2 => $6$Cc0CfuGzHp0pHNSAqdZY9TAzF5YKLc.:17531::0:99999:7:::

user3 => $6$RANDOM3RANDOM3RANDOM3RANDOM3:17531::0:99999:7:::
user3 => $6$P8.89SNhu23Bb2zWHx353t.e9ERSVy.:17531::0:99999:7:::

user4 => $6$RANDOM4RANDOM4RANDOM4RANDOM4:17531::0:99999:7:::
user4 => $6$lFOIUQv1CRG4T0kJQ3rzRNRSyQHjyb1:17531::0:99999:7:::

user5 => $6$RANDOM5RANDOM5RANDOM5RANDOM5:17531::0:99999:7:::
user5 => $6$RZbtYxWiwE$lnP8w64Cp6DgXheacSx.:17531::0:99999:7:::
```